# Using the 'Enter' key while editing ignored tags doesn't submit the tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ignored-tags, tag-watching

When I enter a tagname into the box while editing the ignored tags list, and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to confirm, only a space is added after the tag.

Doing the same action while editing the watched tags list does the expected behaviour, confirming entry of the tag into the list.

Comment: If you're talking about the list at: /users/tag-notifications/<userid> I can not reproduce the problem on Firefox 61.0.2 . The first enter I give confirms the tag from the drop-down suggestions list, and the second enter puts the tag into the ignored tags list, as expected.

Comment: I am talking about the list on /questions. I'll add that into the OP when I'm back behind a propper computer.

Comment: Ok. For that one I also can't reproduce the problem on Firefox. I see the same, expected, behaviour.

Comment: if the autocomplete dropdown is open, the first Enter press will confirm the selection, and the second will add the tag(s) to the list. This works for both Watched and Ignored tags in my testing.

Comment: @Shog9: Hmm, yeah... that kind of makes sense. It would IMO make a lot *more* sense if it worked the same way as the tag entry box under questions, though. (That is, the extra "move the tag from the text box into the tag list above it" step should not even exist, but rather the tag list should be directly editable.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're talking about, @IlmariKaronen; the tag editor on the question page is even *worse* about eating enter keys. It doesn't even close the tag suggestions, it just silently eats them until it's had its fill and tries to submit the question.

Comment: @Shog9: That's actually IMO more intuitive (well, other than the "tries to submit the question" part): if pressing enter *consistently does nothing*, it's clear that you need to do something else (e.g. press space, or just click anything outside the box). In the watched / ignored tags editor, as it currently works, pressing enter does two different things depending on the state of the edit box, and it's not necessarily obvious (especially if you're not actually trying to actively *use* the dropdown menu) what the difference between those two states is. [...]

Comment: [...] Also, in the question tag editor, as soon as you successfully select (or type in) a tag name, it *visually turns into a tag*, making the change from the "in the progress of selecting a tag" state to "successfully selected a tag" obvious. Just making that happen in the watched / ignored tags editor too would IMO be an improvement. But once that's done, why not also prefill the edit box with the currently watched or ignored tags, instead of having them as separate elements above the edit box?

Comment: Anyway, I think this is something where we should try to aim for a consistent UI. Why do we need two different interfaces (which not only look different, but react to the same inputs in different ways) for editing a list of tags?

Comment: Pretty sure there are more'n two, @Ilmari - the dev story has one that looks almost - but not quite - like the one on the question page, and treats the enter key differently than either of the previously-discussed tag editors...

Comment: Thanks to all you guys's feedback. At this point I don't seem to be able to repro the behaviour. Perhaps it was due to using different tags in testing, I can't recall. (Best way to make a bug report :/ ) I can confirm that both watched and ignored tags does the same behaviour for me as well now, first enter selects from dropdown (removing my `[` `]` from around the tag) second enter confirms it into the list.